# ArcObjects update feature attribute

Tags: arcobjects, c#, editing, esri-geodatabase, update

I want to update enabled field of feature in an asp.net MVC application.
I have below code but it returned "No update session in progress" error

```
public string Test()
        {
            IWorkspace workSpace = SdeUtil.rtnWorkSpace(UserEnviromentSetting.UserName.ToUpper());
            IWorkspaceEdit workSpaceEdit = workSpace as IWorkspaceEdit;
            var featureWorkspace = workSpace as IFeatureWorkspace;
            IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("DISCNT_S");
            var feature = featureClass.GetFeature(4801);
            workSpaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
            workSpaceEdit.StartEditOperation();
            var enableInd = feature.Fields.FindField("ENABLED");
            feature.set_Value(enableInd, 0);
            feature.Store();
            workSpaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
            workSpaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
            return "s";
        }
```

Even if I use below code it returned "Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session"

```
IWorkspace workSpace = SdeUtil.rtnWorkSpace(UserEnviromentSetting.UserName.ToUpper());
            IWorkspaceEdit workSpaceEdit = workSpace as IWorkspaceEdit;
            var featureWorkspace = workSpace as IFeatureWorkspace;
            IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("DISCNT_S");
            workSpaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
            workSpaceEdit.StartEditOperation();
            IQueryFilter filter = new QueryFilterClass();
            filter.WhereClause = "OBJECTID = 4801";
            var featureCursor = featureClass.Update(filter, false);
            var feature = featureCursor.NextFeature();
            if (feature != null)
            {
                var enableInd = feature.Fields.FindField("ENABLED");
                feature.set_Value(enableInd, 0);
                feature.Store();
            }
            workSpaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
            workSpaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
            return "s";
```

rtnWorkspace mthod is:

```
public static IWorkspace rtnWorkSpace(string versionName, string serviceName, string userName, string userPass)
        {
            string sSERVER = string.Empty;
            string sInstance = "sde:oracle11g";
            string sPassword = string.Format("{0}@{1}", userPass, serviceName);

            Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory");
            System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            IWorkspaceFactory2 oWorkspaceFactory = obj as IWorkspaceFactory2;

            IPropertySet oPropertySet = new PropertySetClass();
            oPropertySet.SetProperty("SERVER", sSERVER);
            oPropertySet.SetProperty("DATABASE", "");
            oPropertySet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", sInstance);
            oPropertySet.SetProperty("USER", userName);
            oPropertySet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", sPassword);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(versionName))
                oPropertySet.SetProperty("VERSION", "SDE." + versionName);

            IWorkspace worckSpace = oWorkspaceFactory.Open(oPropertySet, 0);
            IEnumDatasetName dsNames = worckSpace.get_DatasetNames(esriDatasetType.esriDTAny);
            return worckSpace;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `featureCursor.UpdateFeature()` (and `featureCursor.Flush()`) instead of `feature.Store()`

Comment: Yes i do but it returns "Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session" exception at ```var featureCursor = featureClass.Update(filter, false);``` row

Comment: This project was a Asp.Net Webforms application. It works well but the issue comes out when i upgraded project to a Asp.Net MVC application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was from license binding. For editing you need to bind extensions as

```
    esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeNetwork,
    esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeDataInteroperability
```